# how to use postgresql function in another function which returns set of Refcursor

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

My Function as Follows

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_history(refcursor, encounterid integer, patientid integer)
>     RETURNS SETOF refcursor
>
> Begin
>
> end

How to use above function in another function.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to return `SETOF refcursor`?

Maybe you want

```
 RETURNS TABLE( ...)
```

or

```
 RETURNS SETOF some_composite_type
```

You call that like any other SELECT command ..

```
SELECT * FROM get_history(...)
```

And can use it in a plpgsql LOOP:

```
FOR my_row_var IN
    SELECT * FROM get_history(...)
LOOP
  -- do stuff
END LOOP;
```

Or just

```
 RETURNS refcursor
```

[There is a detailed example how to handle this in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN57060)

Even including an example for `RETURNS SETOF refcursor`.